# PfSense Unbound deny requests from another Lan

Tags: dns, pfsense, unbound

I have PfSense Home server, with two interfaces,  LAN and Wifi with Captive Portal.

DNS Resolver works perfectly for both, I forced redirection dns trafic at WAN Public DNS to the Firewall itself.
And Wifi Guests are only allowed
to :
DNS port 53 to destination 192.168.200.254
HTTP ans HTTPS for Web navigation.

My problem is :
From Guests Wifi Network,  my client can retrieve all LAN records (192.168.0.254 for example), with nslookup 192.168.200.254.

I would like to deny these Dns requests , I don't want my guests able to know my LAN ips/devices
(Even if yes, other trafic is denied already).